# Excel Interop Range.Replace method not working

Tags: c#, excel, vba, interop, excel-dna

I am trying to write a C# method that will remove all instances of a collection of characters from an Excel spreadsheet.  Using the Range object's Replace method seems like the most efficient way to do this, rather than iterating through each cell.  Here is what I'm working with:

Range extension method:

```
 public static void ReplaceChars(this Range me, String toReplace, String replacement = "") {

        //App is a static reference to the active Excel instance.
        //Alerts must be suppressed for characters that are not present in data.
        App.DisplayAlerts = false; 

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < toReplace.Length; i++) {
            me.Replace(

                //I'm using "Substring(i,1)" rather than "foreach (Char c in toReplace)" 
                //because Excel maps Char values differently than .NET.
                What: toReplace.Substring(i, 1),

                Replacement: replacement,
                LookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart,
                SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                MatchCase: true,
                MatchByte: false, //I'm not 100% what this arg does
                SearchFormat: false, //Or this one
                ReplaceFormat: false); //Or this one
        }

        App.DisplayAlerts = true;
    }
```

Call from main program like this, for example, to leave only punctuation:

```
  App.ActiveSheet.Cells.ReplaceChars(
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
```

Sometimes 'U' will be not get replaced, sometimes 'T', sometimes all digits.  I can't really predict it.  If I comment out setting DisplayAlerts and put a breakpoint in the for loop, I will get alerts on the characters that are not replaced.

Has anyone had issues with Range.Replace like this?  Am I just not assigning arguments correctly?

Comment: I think you are doing this in a most convoluted way. What you are obviously trying to achieve here is to remove all alphanumeric characters in that sheet. While I have no idea what purpose that could serve, I would do this with a RegEx instead. Please clarify what exactly you want to do as I suspect there are much better ways to achieve it.

Comment: My end goal is to find which cells have foreign accented letters or other non-standard punctuation.  So I'm actually replacing all characters on a normal English keyboard.  Checking a regex that filters unicode values against each cell in a master loop was my first choice, but it was executing in exponential time and did not look viable for large files.  The advantage of Range.Replace is that Excel's built-in operations are highly optimized and Excel will take advantage of parallel processing.

Comment: So to find all weird characters on Sheet1, I duplicate it, use Range.Replace on all normal characters on Sheet1 (2). Then all I have to do is check if each cell's .Value.ToString().Length > 0, which executes a lot faster than a Regex.  (Except Range.Replace is not working as I expect it to.)  Then I report the results in Sheet1, and delete Sheet1 (2).

Comment: Still sounds horribly convoluted to me, but hey: if you say it's a lot faster, then that's how to do it. Now you said `I will get alerts on the characters that are not replaced` - Can you please specify? What kind of alerts? `Formula too long` perhaps?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is definitely convoluted.  Good old interop.  2. The alert is the normal Find and Replace message when the queried text is not found.  "Microsoft Excel cannot find any data to replace. Check if your search formatting and criteria are defined correctly.  If you are sure that matching data exists in this workbook, it may be on a protected sheet. Excel cannot replace data on a protected worksheet."  I disable DisplayAlerts to suppress those for any characters that aren't actually in the sheet, but it shows those alerts for the characters it "misses" as well.

Comment: Other relevant points:  1. I've also noticed that the order of characters in the argument to ReplaceChars can affect what is "missed".  For example, putting '/' before the digit characters ensures that dates are removed, whereas all dates will not be properly removed if '/' is after the digits.  2. Find and Replace requires '?' '*' and '~' be escaped with a preceding '~'.  I believe these are the only characters Excel's Find and Replace treats specially, and I am not using them in my call to ReplaceChars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it all has to do will the NumberFormat property of the range in question.  I added this before the replacements and it worked:

```
ws.Cells.NumberFormat = "@" //Set format to text
foreach (Range col in ws.Cells){ 
     //Iterate through columns rather than doing entire range to reduce memory overhead
     col.Value = col.Value //Flatten any lingering dates to text values
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I suspected something of that sort when you mentioned the dates.
Another thing: since MatchCase looks at letters and you replace both lower and upper case letters, you might as well reduce your string to `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"` and set `MatchCase: false`. BTW: `MatchByte` is for Asian characters, so no need for that. You can accept your own answer btw since it does solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the parameter advice.